# How to interact with a Swank server at a low level with telnet?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, swank

I am trying to play with a Swank server from the command line (with no specific production purpose, merely trying to understand things with some hacky ideas in mind for later) and I can't figure out what I can type from a `telnet` session for getting any usable answer; for instance how could I evaluate `(+ 1 1)`?

A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377098/interact-with-a-locally-long-running-common-lisp-image-possibly-daemonized-fro) tells:

> It is indeed possible to communicate with a swank server if you familiarize yourself with the swank protocol, which seems to be underdocumented (see e. g. here: https://github.com/astine/swank-client/blob/master/swank-description.markdown). However, this exposes a TCP socket over a network, which could be unsafe. Once I tried that, too, but I was not satisfied with the IPC speed.

and the link actually gives some hints, but unfortunately no example. I couldn't get any result.

Here is what I tried; after having separately started a server with

```
(swank:create-server :port 4005  :dont-close t :style NIL)
```

I tried things like:

```
~ $ telnet localhost:4005
00001e(swank:listener-eval (+ 1 2))
```

and got the following error message:

```
" "Reader error in file #<string-input stream from \"(swan...\" 0x6045ce0640>, position 20:
Cannot find the external symbol LISTENER-EVAL in #<\"SWANK\" package>.")Connection closed by foreign host
```

What would be in that case the string I should type?

Comment: How about `swank-repl:listener-eval` ?

Comment: Hi @RainerJoswig If I am not wrong I get the answer `Connection closed by foreign host` as soon as I type it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to make this work:

```
00003e(:emacs-rex (swank:interactive-eval "(+ 1 2)") "cl-user" t 8)
```

Notice how there is first an `:emacs-rex` keyword, and how the form to evaluate is in a string. The 8 is just an arbitrary value here. The reply first starts with `00A1C8(:indentation-update ...)`, followed by:

```
000031(:return (:ok "=> 3 (2 bits, #x3, #o3, #b11)") 8)
```