# Get the path of the script that is currently executing in Steel Bank Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm calling a CL script from various places in the system. How do I get the file path of the script that is currently executed?

For example, the script source file is located in the `/home/user/project/source/` directory. The script is being executed from the `/home/user/` directory in the following manner:

`user@machine:~$ ./project/source/script.lsp`

Regardless of the callers location, script should know that it's located in the `/home/user/project/source/` directory.

I've tried using the `*default-pathname-defaults*` variable, but the following command shows the directory from which the script was called:

`(format t "Pathname: ~S~&" *default-pathname-defaults*)`

*Environment: SBCL 1.4.5.debian on Ubuntu 18.04.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*load-truename*` and `*compile-file-truename*` variables are bound to the truename of the file being loaded with `cl:load` or compiled with `cl:compile-file` at the time of loading or compilation, respectively.

In your case, `*load-truename*` is the thing to use. It will give a full, absolute pathname to the script.

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon [one possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839693/6040063) while browsing through different question.

As @Andrei has noted, it's possible to read the full pathname of the script which is invoked by using the following expression:

```
; truename function expands relative path to the script stored in $_ variable
(truename (sb-ext:posix-getenv "_"))
```

Since this solution is relying on `$_` environment variable and bash shell, it may not be portable as @DmitryGrigoryev has noted in [this answer at unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377699).